# Python use format to pass list into string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Can you help me how I can pass list "some" into string "json_req" using format?

```
some = ["3874933","38423894"]
json_req='{"marketIds" : {},"priceProjection" : {"priceData" : ["EX_BEST_OFFERS"]}}'.format(some)
```

The result should be:

```
'{"marketIds" : ["3874933","38423894"],"priceProjection" : {"priceData" : ["EX_BEST_OFFERS"]}}'
```

At the moment I receive an error:

```
KeyError: '"marketIds" '
```

Thanks

Comment: when I try to print it i get KeyError: '"marketIds" '

Comment: Your key doesn't match the JSON data, it includes literal quotes and whitespace.

Comment: @ArthurZangiev, show HOW you've tried to print it and let's correct that part first.

Comment: He's getting a KeyError when he formats the string on the second line. Badly formed format string - not escaping the braces.

Answer (score 2):

If you have braces in a string you are formatting using `format()` you need to escape them by using double braces:

```
json_req='{{"marketIds" : {},"priceProjection" : {{"priceData" : ["EX_BEST_OFFERS"]}}}}'.format(some)
```

That being said, this whole method of generating the json makes me a little uneasy. It feels like you'd be better off using the json module with a native python object and using `dumps` at the end.

```
import json
some = ["3874933","38423894"]
template = {"marketIds" : some, "priceProjection" : {"priceData" : ["EX_BEST_OFFERS"]}}
json_req = json.dumps(template)
```

That'll lead to more flexible code if you need to change stuff later on.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, the json approach is much better. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ArthurZangiev - no problem, if this solution worked for you please mark it as the accepted solution.